# Set Organization statusId to provisional-member in Liferay

Tags: liferay

How do I set the organization's status to provisional-member for the type com.liferay.portal.model.Organization.status ?

When I do

```
GetterUtil.getInteger(PropsUtil.get("sql.data.com.liferay.portal.model.ListType.organization.status"));
```

it sets organization status to full-member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `sql.data.com.liferay.portal.model.ListType.organization.status` is a property in `portal.properties` which you can override in your `portal-ext.properties`.

So you can give the property in your `portal-ext.properties` for `provisional-member` as:

```
#
# Set the default SQL IDs for common objects.
#

sql.data.com.liferay.portal.model.ListType.organization.status=12018
```

The IDs in the `ListType` table more or less remain constant through out versions, atleast I have seen this to be constant from Liferay CE 6.0 to 6.1 EE GA2.

**Another method**
Or else another way would be to have a new property in your `portal-ext.properties` something like:

```
sql.data.com.liferay.portal.model.ListType.organization.status.provisional=12018
```

And then you can get it in your code anywhere by using:

```
GetterUtil.getInteger(PropsUtil.get("sql.data.com.liferay.portal.model.ListType.organization.status.provisional"));
```

But this second would work only for your custom code in your custom-portlet or hook and not in liferay's code.

Hope this gives some help in solving the issue.